# Scraping links from html using beautifulsoup parts

Tags: python, html, ssl, beautifulsoup

I am doing Python for everybody specialization from Coursera the book contains this code which I can't understand properly.

```
# To run this, download the BeautifulSoup zip file
# http://www.py4e.com/code3/bs4.zip
# and unzip it in the same directory as this file

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    print('TAG:', tag)
    print('URL:', tag.get('a', None))
    print('Contents:', tag.contents[0])
    print('Attrs:', tag.attrs)
```

first of all, can someone explain to me this portion of code?

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

what exactly is happening here and how it is ignoring SSL errors.
What exactly is happening in this line.

```
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read() #I know about the urlopen what exactly this context=ctx doing here
```

Third thing

```
print('URL:', tag.get('a', None))
    print('Contents:', tag.contents[0]) #how exactly this content is working and why [0]
    print('Attrs:', tag.attrs)# what are the Attrs:
```

Comment: try referring documentation once at: [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context) link

Comment: ok, let me see if i can understand something from this page.

Comment: try `print(tag.contents)` to see what you have in variable and maybe then you will know why it uses `[0]`

Comment: `context=ctx` - do you know `"positional arguments"` and `"named arguments"` ?

Comment: no idea about `positional Arguments` or `named arguments`